# redirect back to previous route in fat-free framework

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

Is there some way to redirect back to previous route in fat-free framework?

Something similar to `redirect->back()` in laravel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there's not. If you look at Laravel source code, the `back()` function redirects either to the URL contained in the `Referer` HTTP header or to the last URL stored in session.

It's up to you to decide which strategy to choose, but both can easily be implemented with F3.

**1) Referer header**

```
$f3->reroute($f3->get('SERVER.HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Pros: easy to implement.

Cons: if the header is not set, it will redirect to the current page. If the header is set to a different domain, it will redirect to another website.

In order to avoid redirecting to another domain, you need to check that the referer domain matches the website domain:

```
$referer=$f3->get('SERVER.HTTP_REFERER');
if (preg_match('/^https?:\/\/'.preg_quote($f3->HOST,'/').'\//',$referer)) {
  // The referer URL belongs to the website domain
  $f3->reroute($referer);
} else {
  // The referer URL belongs to another domain (or is empty)
  // take some action, for example reroute to current page:
  $f3->reroute();
  // or reroute to homepage
  $f3->reroute('/');
}
```

**2) Session URL**

```
// end of index.php
$f3->run();
$f3->set('SESSION.previousUrl',$f3->REALM);

// redirect code:
$f3->reroute($f3->get('SESSION.previousUrl'));
```

Pros: no risk to redirect to a different domain

Cons: makes it mandatory to use sessions. If you're running a back-office or an app which already makes use of sessions, that's fine, but if you're running a front website, it will prevent pages from being cacheable on the client side.

**3) Query string**

There's also a third alternative, which could work in some specific cases: passing the original URL in the query string.

```
<a href="/target?origin=/origin">Click here></a>
```

```php
// redirect code:
$f3->reroute($f3->get('GET.origin'));
```